# Xcode - stepping over the debugger to cursor location

Tags: xcode, debugging, user-interface

**Is there a way to to step over the debugger to the cursor location?**

In many occasions I want to skip a whole section of code while debugging, in that case I have to put a new breakpoint in the line I want to go to and click the continue execution button. I can't believe Xcode lacks the step over to cursor function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you move the cursor over the line number a little icon comes out that is a little play button That lets you run the code and stop at that selected line.  Give that a try.

Answer (score 4):

Right-click on the line and select "Continue to Here".